# Congestion Control Query for cars on road using Esper Query Language

Tags: java, complex-event-processing, esper

I am receiving the data from a simulation in the following format:
As it can be seen that for the time being there are two cars that are going from Street 7 to Street 11 (as they cross numerous zones where sensors are placed to monitor the movement).

Now I want to stop a signal when the latest time difference between car#1 and car#2 is  only 3 seconds or less.
How can I do that in esper query language.
I have to write a query for complex event processing that will let me generate an event as soon as the above condition is met.
As from the data it can be seen that initially the time when car#1 enters Street#7 is 42500, whereas when car#2 enters Street#7 the time is 42508, making the time difference of 8 secs.

```
    { time: 42500,
      location: { Zone: 'Z3', Street: 'Street#7' },
      carID: 'car#1' }
    ---------------------------------------
    { time: 42502,
      location: { Zone: 'Z5', Street: 'Street#7' },
      carID: 'car#1' }
    ---------------------------------------
    { time: 42502,
      location: { Zone: 'Z1', Street: 'Street#8' },
      carID: 'car#1' }
    ---------------------------------------
    { time: 42504,
      location: { Zone: 'Z4', Street: 'Street#8' },
      carID: 'car#1' }
    ---------------------------------------
    { time: 42505,
      location: { Zone: 'Z5', Street: 'Street#8' },
      carID: 'car#1' }
    ---------------------------------------
    { time: 42505,
      location: { Zone: 'Z1', Street: 'Street#9' },
      carID: 'car#1' }
    ---------------------------------------
    { time: 42507,
      location: { Zone: 'Z4', Street: 'Street#9' },
      carID: 'car#1' }
    ---------------------------------------
    { time: 42508,
      location: { Zone: 'Z3', Street: 'Street#7' },
      carID: 'car#2' }
    ---------------------------------------
    { time: 42508,
      location: { Zone: 'Z5', Street: 'Street#9' },
      carID: 'car#1' }
    ---------------------------------------
    { time: 42508,
      location: { Zone: 'Z1', Street: 'Street#10' },
      carID: 'car#1' }
    ---------------------------------------
    { time: 42509,
      location: { Zone: 'Z4', Street: 'Street#10' },
      carID: 'car#1' }
    ---------------------------------------
    { time: 42509,
      location: { Zone: 'Z5', Street: 'Street#7' },
      carID: 'car#2' }
    ---------------------------------------
    { time: 42509,
      location: { Zone: 'Z1', Street: 'Street#8' },
      carID: 'car#2' }
    ---------------------------------------
    { time: 42511,
      location: { Zone: 'Z5', Street: 'Street#10' },
      carID: 'car#1' }
    ---------------------------------------
    { time: 42511,
      location: { Zone: 'Z1', Street: 'Street#11' },
      carID: 'car#1' }
    ---------------------------------------
    { time: 42511,
      location: { Zone: 'Z4', Street: 'Street#8' },
      carID: 'car#2' }
    ---------------------------------------
    { time: 42512,
      location: { Zone: 'Z4', Street: 'Street#11' },
      carID: 'car#1' }
    ---------------------------------------
    { time: 42512,
      location: { Zone: 'Z5', Street: 'Street#8' },
      carID: 'car#2' }
    ---------------------------------------
    { time: 42512,
      location: { Zone: 'Z1', Street: 'Street#9' },
      carID: 'car#2' }
    ---------------------------------------
    { time: 42513,
      location: { Zone: 'Z5', Street: 'Street#11' },
      carID: 'car#1' }
    ---------------------------------------
    { time: 42513,
      location: { Zone: 'Z1', Street: 'Street#12' },
      carID: 'car#1' }
    ---------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds a bit like a join of events for car 1 with events of car 2. The question is then what subset of events to join. The use case seems to require retaining some history of streets that were visited by each car. For this we could use a length window or a unique window or a union of these windows. Lets use a length window that considers the last 10 streets or events. For example a query like this:

```
select * from Event(carID="car#1").win:length(20) as car1, Event(carID="car#2").win:length(20) as car2 where Math.abs(car1.time-car2.time) > 3 and car1.Location.Street = car2.Location.Street
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.   But just one more hint needed, as car#1 and car#2 are dynamic IDs, how can i select those???  I do not specifically want to hard code it.

Comment: select distinct CarID from CarEvent.win:time_length_batch(10, 100).        How i would use your query after this one?

Comment: select * from CarEvent.win:length(20) as CARS, CarEvent.win:length(20) as CARS_COPY where CARS.CARID != CARS_COPY.CARID AND (CARS.Location.Street = CARS_COPY.Location.Street AND Math.abs(CARS.time-CARS_COPY.time) > 3) ???

Comment: sure, that's one way of self-joining. Maybe a subquery would make this look nicer. Such as "select * from CarEvent as c0 where exists (select * from CarEvent.win:length(20) as c1 where c0.street = c1.street and Math.abs(...))". Put the subquery in the select-clause and use insert-into if there is further filtering to do.